# VBA InStr not finding right part

Tags: vba, string, vbscript

```
temps(X) = "set port name *** DESCRIPTION *** *** PORT ***   "

first = InStr(temps(x), "***")   ' find start postition 
last = InStr(InStr(1, temps(x), "***") + 1, temps(x), "***") 'find end

snip = Mid(temps(x), first, last)

MsgBox (snip)
```

Why does this result in the out put

*** DESCRIPTION *** *** PORT **

and not the expected *** DESCRIPTION ***

Cheers

Aaron

Comment: oh bum I am using MID the wrong way arnt I !!

Comment: ok simple set all vatibls to have same lenth and now working fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`instr` takes the parameters as `string`, `startpos`, `len` ... so it's failing because you've assumed the parameters are: `string`, `startpos`, `endpos`.

You can fix your code by doing this instead:

```
snip = Mid(temps(x), first, last - first)
```

Note as well that your construct:

```
last = InStr(InStr(1, temps(x), "***") + 1, temps(x), "***")
```

can be written more simply. Note that you've already done `Instr(1, temps(s), "***")` once when you got the value for `first`, so you can rewrite that line to the much more simple:

```
last = InStr(first + 1, temps(x), "***")
```

Comment: I dont know why i did it that way, I know full well the syntax for MID, so jsut a Doh moment. to make it simpler I jsut made all the possible "snips" to be \*** XXX \*** format and then its simply MID(string, first, 11), rather than carry out two instr look ups each time. Cheers for the help though